# Gridview Row Command does not fire in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, gridview

I have seen many posts about gridview row command not firing but have not seen any that is browser dependent.

The Gridview row command does not fire in IE 10. The same page works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. In IE, even the Page_Load is not called during post back. I am using it visual studio 2012 in debug mode. I have cleared cache, restarted VS, and even rebooted.

The aspx code is:

```
  <asp:gridview id="gvInstances" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ShowHeader="False" onrowcommand="gvInstances_RowCommand" BackColor="white" BorderColor="#cccccc" BorderStyle="solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" >

  <Columns>
    <asp:ButtonField Text="Select" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" ItemStyle-BorderColor="#cccccc" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1px" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" >
      <ControlStyle CssClass="grdvwButton" />
    </asp:ButtonField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" /> 
  </Columns>
  </asp:gridview>
```

and the aspx.cs code is:

```
public partial class SelectInstance : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvInstances.DataSource = SessionConfig.Instances;
            gvInstances.DataBind();

        }
     }
     protected void gvInstances_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
     {
         if (e.CommandName == "Select")
         {

         }
     }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with above code; I tested in IE 10. Create a new aspx page (without master page). Then place the above code in the new page and debug it.

Comment: So, why it does not work in IE anymore? It used to work a few days ago. Is there some setting in IE that prohibit this from working? Just before reaching this page, I have a login page that posts back correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me.

Is it necessary to use IE 10 to run and debug ur system? Otherwise, u might wan to consider using IE 9 or below, or use different browser to run ur system because i experience several code and asp control issue when i used IE 10 for my asp.net project

Comment: Thanks. Many of the users use IE 10 and we have to test it in that browser too.